# Logmel spectrogram-1 sec audio dataset?

Tags: spectrogram, keyword-spotting

Can I use the below code for 1sec audio dataset which I need to use for Keyword spotting in micro controller. This code is used for 30sec audio dataset for acoustic scene classification.

Same Code can I use for 1sec audio.

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/glegrain/13276fb57007905180f5455be7a3d6cd/raw/tutacousticscenes2016.py